# Force include in php.ini?

Tags: php, include, require

Is there anything I can change in **php.ini** that includes a php file before running any other file? The equivalent of adding *"require('somefile.php');"* before every file?

Comment: auto_prepend_file

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`auto_prepend_file` directive.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

Comment: To my downvoter, could you clarify what you find wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Search for `auto_prepend_file = [path/to/file]` in php.ini. Replace `[path/to/file]` with your file

Comment: To my downvoter, could you clarify what you find wrong with my answer?